# attempt to invoke a virtual method on null object with onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I'm sure this question has been asked a few times; however, after searching for a while, all I find is "to declare the variable before calling the clicklistner" I've done that already. But still getting the same error. If someone can let me know why the clicklistener called on the getQuoteBotton is giving the following error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

mainActivity

```
package com.example.george.radonquote;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.george.radonquote.R.layout.activity_main;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView titleTextView;
    ImageView mainImageView;
    Button getQuoteBotton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_title);
        mainImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.main_image);
        getQuoteBotton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_quote_btn);

        getQuoteBotton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent quoteActivityIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), QuotesActivity.class);
                startActivity(quoteActivityIntent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#154350"
    tools:context="com.example.george.radonquote.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random Quotes"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="27dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/main_title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/vector_socrates"
        android:id="@+id/main_image"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_title"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_quote_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="get quote" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why did you explicitly import the layout? Please remove that import and then simply `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` then clean your project and build;

Comment: that's just the same as what I have setContentView(activity_main)

Comment: Seems like your views are null, which means your main_activity.xml wasn't been associated to the activity. I would suggest you to use your layout id directly (setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)) and if it still doesn't work, try to clear your project.